# What can knock to the 9990 port if I changes server configurations? REST java WildFly

Tags: java, rest, maven, wildfly

I changed my WildFly ports 
`8080 -> 8081`
`9990 -> 9991`
And my server works perfect.
But when I try to deploy [EXAMPLE](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/10.x/guide/KitchensinkQuickstart.asciidoc) app it tryes to connect 9990 port, but I do not see anything in it's pom which has default 9990 port.

Also I modifyed `arquillian.xml` to change managementPort:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
     http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">  
 <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />

 <!-- Example configuration for a remote WildFly instance -->
 <container qualifier="jboss" default="true">
      <!-- By default, arquillian will use the JBOSS_HOME environment variable.    Alternatively, the configuration below can be uncommented. -->
    <configuration>
    <!--<property name="jbossHome">/path/to/wildfly</property> -->
        <property name="managementPort">9991</property>
    </configuration>
```

This is pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.wildfly.quickstarts</groupId>
<artifactId>wildfly-kitchensink</artifactId>
<version>10.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>WildFly Quickstart: kitchensink</name>
<description>A starter Java EE 7 webapp project for use on JBoss WildFly / WildFly, generated from the jboss-javaee6-webapp archetype</description>
<url>http://wildfly.org</url>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
    </license>
</licenses>

<properties>
    <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following
        message: -->
    <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered
        resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
    <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>

    <!-- Define the version of the JBoss BOMs we want to import to specify
        tested stacks. -->
    <version.jboss.bom>10.1.0.Final</version.jboss.bom>

    <!-- other plug-in versions -->
    <version.surefire.plugin>2.10</version.surefire.plugin>
    <version.war.plugin>3.0.0</version.war.plugin>

    <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 7 APIs including a Bill
            of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection)
            of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions
            of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools stack (you can
            read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs, with some extras tools
            for your project, such as Arquillian for testing) and the jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate
            stack you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs, with extras
            from the Hibernate family of projects) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-javaee7-with-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <!-- First declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. All
        of them are provided by WildFly -->

    <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in
        WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope
        as the API is included in WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included
        in WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in
        WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in
        WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Bean Validation Implementation -->
    <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
    <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in
        WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Now we declare any tools needed -->

    <!-- Annotation processor to generate the JPA metamodel classes for
        typesafe criteria queries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Annotation processor that raising compilation errors whenever constraint
        annotations are incorrectly used. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Needed for running tests (you may also use TestNG) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Optional, but highly recommended -->
    <!-- Arquillian allows you to test enterprise code such as EJBs and Transactional(JTA)
        JPA from JUnit/TestNG -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the name
        given to the generated WAR, and hence the context root) -->
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Java EE doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- The WildFly plug-in deploys the WAR to a local WildFly container -->
        <!-- To use, run: mvn package wildfly:deploy -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- The default profile skips all tests, though you can tune it to run
            just unit tests based on a custom pattern -->
        <!-- Separate profiles are provided for running all tests, including Arquillian
            tests that execute in the specified container -->
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests in your
            WildFly instance -->
        <!-- This profile will start a new WildFly instance, and execute the
            test, shutting it down when done -->
        <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-managed -->
        <id>arq-wildfly-managed</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests in a remote
            WildFly instance -->
        <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-remote -->
        <id>arq-wildfly-remote</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when
            invoking mvn. -->
        <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app
            will need. -->
        <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'deployments'
            folder. -->
        <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
        <id>openshift</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                    <port>9991</port> <!--this I added, but not sure I need it -->
                        <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                        <warName>ROOT</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

But I still recieving:

```
    java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012174: Could not connect to http-remoting://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection failed
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:129)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:71)
    at org.wildfly.plugin.common.AbstractServerConnection.isDomainServer(AbstractServerConnection.java:245)
    at org.wildfly.plugin.common.AbstractServerConnection.getClient(AbstractServerConnection.java:162)
    at org.wildfly.plugin.common.AbstractServerConnection.isDomainServer(AbstractServerConnection.java:139)
    at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.validate(AbstractDeployment.java:192)
    at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.doExecute(AbstractDeployment.java:136)
    at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractAppDeployment.doExecute(AbstractAppDeployment.java:70)
    at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.execute(AbstractDeployment.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012174: Could not connect to http-remoting://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection failed
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager$EstablishingConnection.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:256)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.FutureManagementChannel$Establishing.getChannel(FutureManagementChannel.java:204)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient.getOrCreateChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:148)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient$1.getChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:67)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:117)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:92)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeRequest(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:236)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:141)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:127)
    ... 30 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid response
    at org.xnio.http.HttpUpgradeParser.parseVersion(HttpUpgradeParser.java:150)
    at org.xnio.http.HttpUpgradeParser.parse(HttpUpgradeParser.java:53)
    at org.xnio.http.HttpUpgrade$HttpUpgradeState$UpgradeResultListener.handleEvent(HttpUpgrade.java:301)
    at org.xnio.http.HttpUpgrade$HttpUpgradeState$UpgradeResultListener.handleEvent(HttpUpgrade.java:281)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:87)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:539)
    at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:272)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:253)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:351)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:339)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connect(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:78)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:109)
    ... 40 more
```

What am I missing again? :)

Comment: Is that a typo in the question? The pom has 9091 as the port, not 9090 as you describe it. The problem is that it tries to connect to port 9090 regardless, am I right?

Comment: Yes, but something is trying to connect 9990, I have no idea what is it. There is no configuration for 9990 port in whole project.

Comment: @Gimby Yes, but something is trying to connect 9990, I have no idea what is it. There is no configuration for 9990 port in whole project, but something trying to connect (by default??) I cant find.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

I have missed maven-plugin configuration:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <hostname>${wildfly-hostname}</hostname>
                <port>9991</port>
                <username>${wildfly-username}</username>
                <password>${wildfly-password}</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```